# Can't create a database in list activity

Tags: android, database

I am trying to create a database in listactivity on a button click.. but I am getting an error

> The method
>   openOrCreateDatabase(String, int,
>   null) is undefined for the type new
>   View.OnClickListener(){}" and
>   "DefaultDBHelper cannot be resolved.

Is there any way doing this in a listactivity? Please help !!!

my code :

```
reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
   private int count;
   @Override public void onClick(View v) 
   {
      SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
      try 
      { 
          /* Create the Database (no Errors if it already exists) */
          // myDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          // dbHelper.onCreate(myDB);
          myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
                       + DefaultDBHelper.MY_DATABASE_TABLE 
                       + " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," 
                       + " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

          myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " 
                       + DefaultDBHelper.MY_DATABASE_TABLE 
                       + " (LastName, FirstName, Country, Age)" 
                       + " VALUES ('name', 'title', 'country', 20);"); 
      }
      catch (SQLiteException e) { 
      } 
      finally { 
         if (myDB != null) 
            myDB.close(); 
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u just change the  code like this

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
```

i thought it will help u

Answer (score 0):

```
 reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 SQLiteDatabase myDB =openOrCreateDatabase("DB_NAME", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE ,null);



            }
        });
```

The following code will work.I have tested it.The '**this**' was refering to the OnClickListener object that you had created there.That was causing the compilation error.Taking out '**this**' will solve the issue

Comment: great it worked perfectly and i learned a new thing too...thanks a lot

Comment: Find time to accept one of the answers which you feel is correct.